# Format number with currency and two digits

Tags: .net, vb.net, currency-formatting

I am just getting started with object-oriented programming. I have this homework where I have to generate the following output

$ 1215,51

and my program returns  1215.50625

This is my code, where `a` is the number (double) I am printing

```
txtRe.Text += "Après " + CStr(i) + " ans " + " ==>" + CStr(a) & Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may utilize:

```
   value.ToString("C2")
```

or following your code:

```
   txtRe.Text += "Après " + i.ToString("C2")
```

or even:

```
     Dim value As Double = 12345.6789
     Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
     Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I used it and it worked. However could yo explain what C2 means ???

Comment: Currency, 2 decimals after. You may see the entire explain here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx ... And, since it helped you, please vote if you think I deserve it.  :)  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using US or British current culture (hence a decimal point in your result and not a comma, which is what is used in French). However, if you were to simply set the culture to French and tried to use the standard currency formatter it'd likely throw out a Euro symbol, and that would be after your numeric value. The simplest ways would be to use French culture (to get the comma instead of the decimal point) and put in the '$' symbol manually, converting your double value to fixed-point notation.

```
Dim frenchCulture As New CultureInfo("fr-FR")
Dim result As String = "$" & a.ToString("f2", frenchCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use string.Format, and change culture when needed (Ej: if you use french culture and you want $ symbol).

```
//without culture
String.Format("Après {0} ans ==> {1:C2} {2}", i, a, Environment.NewLine)

//with culture
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
String.Format(culture ,"Après {0} ans ==> {1:C2} {2}", i, a, Environment.NewLine)
```